# Data for specific user Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have read up on Firebase database documentation and I am understanding the basics. But what if I want each user to have their own "list?"

So each user loads up their own list and edits, basically CRUD's their own list? I have created the authentication already, but I am not sure how to proceed here?

Answer (score 2):

So you'd store the data for each user under their own user id (uid):

```
userdata
    <uid>
        data1: value1
        data2: value2
```

Now each user can read their own data with:

```
var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var ref = firebase.database().ref('userdata').child(currentUser.uid);
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

That's JavaScript syntax btw. Translate it to Android with the help of the Android guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

And then you [secure access to that data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) with these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "userdata": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a field with username/id to each record and you filter by that field